# Migrate existing B2C directory to new experience

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2C directory (6 months old) and the portal says there's a new streamlined user flow (see image below) - is that only for new tenants or is there a way to migrate?

Clicking the purple message directs me off to my main hosting tenant, to the page where you create a new B2C Directory.  On that portal page there's a single link, which takes you off to the [B2C product page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/trial/get-started-active-directory-b2c/)

[image]

Update - here's my repro steps:

1) login to azure portal on my main Azure subscription

2) Hit filter button ('Directory + Subscription') to change to B2C directory

3) go to Azure AD B2C blade as per above screenshot

4) click purple bar ("The new B2C experience is here...") (the link on this is https://portal.azure.com/#)

5) a new tab opens which takes you back to the Azure AD B2C blade in the hosting tenant (as per step 1):

[image]

6) if you click the "Get started..." link it takes you off the product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this thanks to re-reading @Sunny Sun's comments, which I misunderstood the first time round.

The trick here is that your default directory must be set to the target B2C directory and not (as was my default) to my main subscription directory.

You can change the default directory via the filter button ('Directory + Subscription') as per the image below and then change it back once the change has taken place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this experience, you just click the prompts, then it will redirect you to the new experience.

From you shown picture, you already use this new experience.

I post my experience here, you can see the new experience is just update `user flows(preview)` to `policies`. And the new policies will be very convenient for you to use.
[image]

The user flows(preview) vs policies:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Sunny.  Unfortunately when I click on the purple bar I get taken off to my hosting tenant (where you normally create a new B2C directory) which then directs you to the product page.  Also, I don't see the 'User flows (Preview)' item that you have in your screenshots.

Comment: Could you try again? And then check the process is the same with the post?

Comment: Besides, if the sign-in account has more than one tenant and the default tenant is not your B2C?

Comment: I've updated the question with my steps.  To be clear about the tenants / directories - I have a main Azure subscription which houses all of my Azure resources.  When I originally started the B2C directory the get started process created a new directory, separate from my main Azure AD directory.  My understanding is that this is how it works - ie I have to be logged in to the B2C directory from where I can then only see the B2C resource?

Comment: You could create the new user in the B2C as the global admin. By this, you could directly login the B2C tenant, and there will be not any link to your AAD.

Comment: Hi Sunny, I'm not sure I understand.  I'm trying to get the new functionality in an existing B2C directory.  At the moment I can't see what's missing.  The purple bar says there's a new experience but clicking it only takes you to the product page.  Can I convert this existing directory or not?

Comment: Of course, you could convert it. But you had better set the b2c tenant as the default directory for the sign-in user.

Comment: ok, that’s great. in that case ‘how’ do I convert it, as currently, clicking the purple bar takes you to the product page and not to the new experience as per your image above?

Comment: Hi Sunny, Yes, I've tried again and it's still exactly the same problem as the original question.  Clicking the purple bar ("The new B2C experience is here....") does not update the UI in the way that it does in your images - it still just goes back to my original azure subscription and invites me to create a new B2C tenant.

Comment: For your problem, I suggest you request support in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com). For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit stuck then as support isn't included in my subscription for B2C

Comment: Apologies @Sunny I've re-read your advice in the comments above and now understood what you meant about setting the B2C tenant as the default directory.  So I'm all good.  Thanks very much for your help.